"bake" light within three.js
In my three.js project, i have a static scene, that I want to add lighting and shadow to. Since its static, I dont need to re-calculate lights and shadow each frame. When it comes to shadows, I can simply set
        this._renderer.shadowMap.autoUpdate = false;
        this._renderer.shadowMap.needsUpdate = false;

after the first render call. Is there something similar for lighting ? I know i can bake lights in blender, but I would prefer to do it within three.js.
I tried researching, but couldnt find anyhing so far.

are you seeing a performance hit? like stuttering frames or anything?  What's driving you to want to do this? I'm just curious

A quick look through docs comes to the same conclusion as yourself. adjust the autoUpdate to false then you can choose which frames to assign needsUpdate to true

You may be interested in:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/LightProbe
and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18371

@ThisGuy yes. I have a bunch of point lights in my scene. FPS is much lower with compared to without.
